# using str_replace for get all images of csv magento

Tags: php, string, magento, csv

Hello guys I have a csv of my providers with this format.

> urlimagexx.jpg, urlimageyyy.jpg, urlimagezzz.jpg

And in my script for importing directly into Magento, I have this code.

```
$fullpath = '/tmp/'.basename($rfullpath);

       // $rfullpath = str_replace(',','%20', $rfullpath);
       // $rfullpath = rtrim($rfullpath, '%20');
        $rfullpath = str_replace(' ', '%20', $rfullpath);
        $rfullpath = rtrim($rfullpath, '%20');



        $rimagen = file_get_contents($rfullpath);
        file_put_contents($fullpath, $rimagen)
```

I've tried with the commented code but doesn't work.
Can you help me ?

other example
one example

http://www.tecnostar.es/assets/productos/moviles/fundas/1463799.jpg,http://www.tecnostar.es/assets/productos/moviles/fundas/1463799_1.jpg,http://www.tecnostar.es/assets/productos/moviles/fundas/1463799_3.jpg,http://www.tecnostar.es/assets/productos/moviles/fundas/1463799_4.jpg

my script have this code

```
  for($i=11; $i>=11; $i--)
    {
        $rfullpath = $csv[$i];

        if(!substr_count($rfullpath, 'http')) continue;

        $fullpath = '/tmp/'.basename($rfullpath);

       // $rfullpath = str_replace(',','%20', $rfullpath);
       // $rfullpath = rtrim($rfullpath, '%20');
        $rfullpath = preg_replace('%\,/%','%20', $rfullpath);
        $rfullpath = rtrim($rfullpath, '%20');


        $product->setImage_label($data['name']); //para titulo imagenes  (prueba) //para las imagenes titulos
        $rimagen = file_get_contents($rfullpath);
        file_put_contents($fullpath, $rimagen);

        try {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath ,array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail') , false, false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //echo " FAIL imagen $i $rfullpath\n";
            file_put_contents('fallos.txt', $data['sku']." imagen $i $rfullpath\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but not works, the product image get a 404 error if upload ony a 1 url of image works.

Comment: Please, specify `not works`. You don't get the desired result? You get an error?

Comment: only put a 1 image, the others images not are imported to the product.

Comment: not have a error only not upload to magento the second or third image